# Missing $\{2,p\}$-Hall subgroups in finite non-abelian simple groups

Tags: group-theory, finite-groups, representation-theory, simple-groups

Can anybody tell me how to prove this theorem?

> **Theorem**: Suppose that $G$ is a finite non-abelian simple group. Then there exists an odd prime $p\in\pi(G)$ such that $G$ has no $\{2,p\}$-Hall subgroup.

Comment: Did you see the related (but different) question http://mathoverflow.net/questions/119220/an-extension-of-the-converse-to-halls-theorem ?

Comment: Did you try proving the contrapositive?