# About simple groups and Hall subgroups.

Tags: finite-groups, simple-groups

Eight months ago, I submitted a research paper to a good impact factored journal and I got a rejection today. I received the following comment from the reviewer. 
He suggested that that I submit the paper somewhere else. Also, he stated that there is a hole in the proof of one of my corollaries. He said that the following lemma:

Lemma: Let $r$ be a prime number. Then, for every simple group $S$ with $r \in \pi (S)$, there exists $s \in \pi (S)$ such that $S$ does not possess a Hall $\{r,s\}$-subgroup, where $\pi (S)$ is the set of the prime divisors of $S$.

which I used in the proof of the corollary is not true when $r = 3$ and that $SL(2,7)$ is a counterexample. The above Lemma is already published by some authors in a good journal.

My questions:

1) I checked with gap software and found that indeed $SL(2,7)$ has Hall $\{3,2\}$-subgroup and Hall $\{3,7\}$-subgroup. However, $SL(2,7)$ is not a simple group. Hence it is not a counterexample for the Lemma. Am I right regarding this?

2) I checked my paper and found that, in four out of nine of my results, I have used this lemma by applying it directly in the proof or indirectly by applying another theorem which has used this lemma within its proof. If I pointed this to the editor, is there a chance that he\she may reconsider the status of my paper?

Comment: I think this should be taken up with the editor directly.  Mistakes do happen during peer review, of course.  When they are detected they should be corrected, like any other errors.

Comment: You are certainly right in that $\text{SL}(2,7)$ is not simple. I'd advise checking carefully whether $\text{PSL}(2,7)$ is a counterexample.

Comment: Could you give a reference for that lemma? It looks a lot stronger than what is mentioned at https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/510077/missing-2-p-hall-subgroups-in-finite-non-abelian-simple-groups?rq=1 and the linked question  https://mathoverflow.net/questions/119220/an-extension-of-the-converse-to-halls-theorem

Comment: A. A. Heliel, A. Ballester-Bolinches, R. Esteban-Romero, and M. O. Almestady, “Z-permutable subgroups of finite groups,” Monatshefte für Mathematik, vol. 179, no. 4, pp. 523–534, Apr. 2016.

Comment: @TobiasKildetoft It is Lemma 3 in the above reference.

Comment: I tried $PSL(2,7)$ and I think it is a counterexample for $r=3$. Can some one confirm it with me?

Comment: I agree that you have found a counter example there. I took a look at the lemma in question, and the proof is a terrible one by cases that I did not feel like working through.